# protractor to pass site authentication as cookies to run tests in safari

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor test. The website under test is  `https://aaa:pwd@test.com`. It is a htaccess-apache level authentication. How should i set it to use in safari browser from selenium. When passed from the url like above, it still asks for authentication. (I have no issues using this url in chrome and firefox. It does not work for safari or edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like basic authentication is not supported since Safari 10. Reference: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Troubleshooting+%28General%29+-+Basic+Authentication+on+Safari

The workaround would be to code in the steps to login manually.